# Translate ASP.NET web application to Lift application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, scala, lift

I would like to create a web application(maybe a shopping cart) in ASP.NET and after that I would like to translate this application in a Lift web application. I know the basics of Scala programming. My questions:

1) Do you know some links with differences in standard controls (label, button, radio button etc.) between ASP.NET and Lift framework?

2) Can I store the results of these two applications in one common database? I think I can use something like SOAP protocol.

3) In your experience, how easy or difficult is this kind of 'translation'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by translate.  Do you mean actually run it through a tranlation process that converts the implementation from one language to another.  If so then I think you have bitten into a really large problem.  If you mean you just want to implement the same thing in a different lanugage then that should be doable.

1. There is no correlation here.  In ASP.NET the controls are there to write a bunch of code behind the scenes for you.  There is no equivalent in LIFT.   Try looking at it like a MVC problem, and assume you only have HTML output.
2. Yes, you could have a middle tier that uses soap, rest, JSON, whatever and stores it in a DB.  But you could just connect both languages to a mysql database directly from the front tier to.
3. Implementing the same solution in two different languages is variable based on your skill in both languages.